# Initializing array first with size(indexs) greater than 1, then array with size 1, breaks the former array, if no other array is initialised with it

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings

Problematic program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main() {
char s[100],f[1];
scanf("%s",&s);
scanf("%s",&f);
printf("\n%s %s",s,f);
}
```

output is empty for s, while f is read properly.
while if we switch `f[1]` and `s[100]`, or initialise f with size larger than 1, or initialize any other larger than 1 array, then it works as it should.
(this is a stripped down version of program, to the essential problematic part)

tried swapping f[1] and s[100] which works, but when placed in the mentioned order, it breaks.

Comment: `f` can only hold a string of length 0. `scanf("%s",&f);` will result in _undefined behaviour_ (google that term) for any string entered longer than 0. Be aware that undefined behaviour includes "apparently working as I expect".

Comment: but the thing is, if I print s and f seperately, s is empty, while f shows the entered character. IDK why

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. You're overwriting past the end of the `f` array and this yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. One possible speculation of what happens is that you read anything but `'\0'` into `f` and the terminator `'\0'` into the immediatly following `s` in memory. Which overwrites whatever you had there with the "empty" signaling terminator 0.

Comment: so I printed it's pointer, and s preceeds f in memory space, so, should it overwrite it?

Comment: I vote to close as another instance of the typo/thinko of forgetting the terminator.

Comment: No not "it should overwrite it", it might. And next time it will format your harddisk. Undefined behaviour, really really important to understand.

Comment: @vbansal21 if you want to know what is actually happening, you need to execute your code with a debugger stepping through the assembly code.

Comment: okay, sure, thanks for the info, and taking your time to reply.

Comment: Never, never, never... do `scanf("%s" ....` It's just as bad as using `gets`. Always, always, always... use a "maximum field width" specifier. And that shall be (at most) array size minus 1. And that tells you why scanning into `f[1]` is meaningless.

Comment: `&s` in `scanf` is wrong. For arrays you don't use `&s` just use `s`

Comment: And always, always, always... check the return value of `scanf`